# Directx9 surface to texture

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, textures, geometry-surface

I want to capture my Backbuffer into my LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 and then copy the surface into my IDirect3DTexture9 finally use that texture as my object skin. I wrote the codes but just received black pixels.

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texture;
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pd3dsBack = NULL;

void init()//init point
{

    D3DXCreateTexture(g_pd3dDevice, 640, 480, D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC,
        0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &texture);

}

void render()//render point
{

    g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene();

    g_pd3dDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
        D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 0);

    //my scene (1) 3d objects codes for draw.

    g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();

    //now try to get back-buffer into surface

    g_pd3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pd3dsBack);


    //i add this Save section to ensure the backbuffer data received complete and work.(it was ok and save complete true picture of Scene(1) ).

    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileA("BackbufferImage.BMP", D3DXIFF_BMP, pd3dsBack, NULL, NULL);


    //this line put surface into my texture ; if u think this way is false please give me a simple code to fill texture by surface.

    texture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pd3dsBack);

    pd3dsBack->Release();//release my surface


                         //scene(2)
    g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene();

    g_pd3dDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
        D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 0);

    //now render my scene(2) and useing the texture object for draw it as skin of my 3d     object
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, texture);

    g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();


    g_pd3dDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 l_Device= RenderManager()->GetDirectXDevice();
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 l_RenderTarget, l_Surface;

m_Texture->GetSurfaceLevel(0,&l_Surface);
l_Device->GetRenderTarget(IdStage,&l_RenderTarget);
l_Device->StretchRect(l_RenderTarget,NULL, l_Surface,NULL,D3DTEXF_NONE);
l_RenderTarget->Release();
```

Where **IdStage** is current render target you want to copy, in your case it will be 0

**m_Texture** is a DirectX Texture that you want to receive the copy from the backbuffer

Comment: Thank you carlos for your help.i do it but nothing change.(maybe i do it wrong)so could you please look into my code edited by your code here.it's complete and you can compile it too.

Comment: Try changing the 0 parameter in Create texture to 1.

D3DXCreateTexture(g_pd3dDevice,640,480,D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, 1,D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &My_3DTexture);

Answer (score 4):

One Another way:

***Step 1:*** Get the back buffer as a surface:

```
 LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pBackBuffer;
 GetBackBuffer(0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer)
```

***Step 2:*** Create an Empty texture

```
 LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textureMap
 D3DXCreateTexture(device, width, height, D3DX_DEFAULT,  D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, 
                                 D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&textureMap);
```

Note: If you want the alpha channel then use D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8 format.

***Step 3:*** Get the pointer which is pointing to the top surface of the empty texture

```
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pTexSurface;
textureMap->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pTexSurface);
```

***Step 4:*** Surface to Surface Copy (back buffer surface to empty surface)

```
StretchRect(pBBsurface, NULL, pTexSurface, NULL, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

***Step 5:*** Resultant texture with back buffer content

```
textureMap
```